# File changed action

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I need to monitor some **single** file for changes and react **immediately** when it changed.

Is it correct to solve this task with *while(true)* approach?
Please, advice better solution if exists.

test code:

```
        File file = new File("d:\\clipboard-buffer.txt");

        long lastFileChangedTime = file.lastModified();

        while (true) {
            long fileChangedTime = file.lastModified();
            if (fileChangedTime != lastFileChangedTime) {
                System.out.println("File has modificated");
                lastFileChangedTime = fileChangedTime;
            }
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
```

I'm looking for simple ways and don't need third-party libraries.

Comment: The `WatchService` API is part of Java.

Comment: It monitors all directory, as I know.

Comment: You can configure it to watch exactly what you need.

Comment: And in dir with 10k files it would work as fast as the code above?

Comment: Probably faster. You can do appropriate benchmarking.